# How can I recover YARV-compiled Source Code of ruby

Tags: android, ruby, reverse-engineering, rhomobile, yarv

I have developed an app using **[Rhomobile](https://github.com/rhomobile/rhodes/)**, which is a cross-platform native mobile applications using web-technologies: HTML, CSS, JavaScript and Ruby, but unfortunately now I don't have the source code as I've lost it, but I have the `apk` that I built at the time. several readings shows it is possible to recover it by `reversing the apk` which I did but then in the `assets\apps\app` I got YARV-bytecode which definitely requires to be restored to the ruby source. I saw some tools like [reversal](https://github.com/michaeledgar/reversal) which advertised as `YARV to Ruby` but didn't worked for me. in the examples [reversal](https://github.com/michaeledgar/reversal) given YARV-bytecode appeared there are somehow different to those I found from the `apk` I pulled from.
Mine is a shown below:

[image: mydesktopERP.iseq]

How can I recover it?

Please help this.

Answer (score -1):

No it is not possible to recover the code.